# Magento2, aroundSave event does not get triggered on product save

Tags: magento2, product, plugin

Considering below in `di.xml`, wondering why I do not see my message in blog after pressing `save` button on product page in admin panel.

in di.xml :

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="aroundProductSave" type="\mtVendor\myModule\Plugin\AroundProductRepositorySave"/>
</type>
```

in AroundProductRepositorySave.php :

```
public function aroundSave(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product,
        $saveOptions = false
    ) {
        $this->log->debug("------------ in AroundProductRepositorySave -------------");

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $result
         */
        $result = $proceed($product, $saveOptions);
        //return $result;

        return $subject->get($product->getSku(), false, $product->getStoreId(), true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That would be because the admin product form doesn't actually use `ProductRepository`, at least as of 2.2.2.

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php:

```
                $product->save();
```

You haven't explained what you're actually trying to accomplish, but you would probably be better served by an observer on event `catalog_product_save_before` or `catalog_product_save_after`. Those are kicked off by the product resource model, so they should fire regardless of whether the product is saved via `ProductRepository` or directly.